# Running treeNetwork in Rstudio

Tags: r, networkd3

I would like to use the `treeNetwork` function [here](https://rdrr.io/github/christophergandrud/networkD3/man/treeNetwork.html#heading-1) in RStudio. I open with `library(networkD3)` but the command `treeNetwork` is not recognised in Rstudio, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `treeNetwork()` function is only available in the "dev" version, not the CRAN released version. You can install the dev version with...

```r
devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
```